# Getting the position of the largest value in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say that I have the following matrix in MATLAB:

```
I=[2 1;4 5];
```

How can I retrieve the position of the largest element??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
[value, location] = max(I(:));
[row,col] = ind2sub(size(I), location);

>> [row, col]                            

ans =

     2     2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get index as follow:

```
[~, idx] = max(I(:))
```

and then use it

```
I(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `find`:

```
[row, col] = find(I == max(I(:)))
row =  2
col =  2
```